# Export variable from React class component for Jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I tried to test a RegExp object from a .tsx file and I get this error when I try to execute my test scripts:

```
 Test suite failed to run
                                                                                                                                                        
 Jest encountered an unexpected token

 This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.
```

How can I parse part of a TypeScript object? I tried installing **ts-jest** but then I get an error saying `Cannot use import statement outside module`.

I am working on a React project that has unit tests for some JavaScript functions using Jest but nothing more. There is a RegExp validation for an input field in a React class component that I need to test.
I defined the regular expression outside the React class component but in the same file and I exported it:

*myClassComponent.tsx*:

```
export const myRegExp: RegExp = new RegExp(/(^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{4}$)/);
```

I created *regExpTest.js*:

```
const myRegExp = require('../../src/components/myClassComponent');

export const regExpTest = () =>
{
    describe('myRegExp test suite', () => {
        test('', () => {
            expect('value').toMatch(myRegExp)
        })
    });
}

module.exports = regExpTest;
```

I have a *tests.js* inside my *scripts* folder that I use to execute all my test suites with **npm test**:

```
const regExpTest  = require('../test/regExpTest');

regExpTest();
```

Comment: What about const { myRegExp }  = require('../../src/components/myClassComponent');

Comment: As it is a named export and not a default export, it requires destructuring.

Comment: After changing it, I get an error complaining about a missing semicolon in the myClassComponent.tsx file. I think this is because Jest cannot parse  the TypeScript file correctly because there is no missing semicolon, just a type declaration.

Comment: You should compile the tsx and import the .js version in the test: const myRegExp = require('../../src/components/myClassComponent.js');

Comment: Is there some other way that allows me to test both .js and .ts files without compiling?

Comment: You have to configure the testing framework accordingly.